# python, can't import Google Cloud Pub/Sub package

Tags: python-3.5, google-cloud-pubsub

My script work normally, but the error occur when I run it on the docker.

```
app_1  |     from google.cloud import pubsub
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
app_1  |     from google.cloud.pubsub.client import Client
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub/client.py", line 19, in <module>
app_1  |     from google.cloud.client import ClientWithProject
app_1  | ImportError: cannot import name 'ClientWithProject'
```

In docker requirement, I added google-cloud-pubsub==0.23.0

Comment: I got the same issue, installed `google-cloud` and it worked! I think it works as well `google-cloud-core`, because `google-cloud-pubsub` seem to miss `client` import which is in core.

Comment: I change google-cloud-pubsub==0.23.00 and this work. Amazing